# What is "extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Textrepresentable" doing in this example?

Tags: swift

I get this protocol and the struct implementing it.

```
 protocol TextRepresentable {
    var textualDescription: String { get }
}


struct Hamster: Textrepresentable {
    var name: String
    var textualDescription: String {
        return "A hamster named \(name)"
    }
}
```

How is this code below working?

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: TextRepresentable {
    var textualDescription: String {
        let itemsAsText = self.map { $0.textualDescription }
        return "[" + itemsAsText.joined(separator: ", ") + "]"
    }
}
```

What is extension collection doing to this code below?

```
let murrayTheHamster = Hamster(name: "Murray")
let morganTheHamster = Hamster(name: "Morgan")
let mauriceTheHamster = Hamster(name: "Maurice")
let hamsters = [murrayTheHamster, morganTheHamster, mauriceTheHamster]

print(hamsters.textualDescription)
```

Comment: By the way, the Swift Standard Library already has protocols to model this functionality (`CustomStringConvertible` and `CustomDebugStringConvertible`)

Comment: @Alexander I don't have any idea about that my dear, I just want to learn how things work in swift, and the answer below has ended my confusion. :)

Answer (score 3):

This code

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: TextRepresentable {
    var textualDescription: String {
        let itemsAsText = self.map { $0.textualDescription }
        return "[" + itemsAsText.joined(separator: ", ") + "]"
    }
}
```

creates an extension on `Collection` that is only valid when the elements in the `Collection` **are** `TextRepresentable` (ie. conform to the protocol `TextRepresentable`). 
If that is the case for a `Collection` (`Array` is a `Collection`) the extension adds a computed property `textualDescription` to the `Collection`.

In your sample code `hamsters` contains only objects of type `Hamster` which conforms to `TextRepresentable`. Thus, the compiler knows the extension is valid for your `Array` `hamsters` and the property `textualDescription` is available.

The implementation of `textualDescription` is also fairly straightforward.

```
// Defines a property named textualDescription of type String
var textualDescription: String { 

    // Calls textualDescription on every element of the array 
    // and adds the return values to a new array itemsAsText
    let itemsAsText = self.map { $0.textualDescription }

    // Creates a string starting with "[" followed by 
    // all the elements in itemsAsText, separated by ",",
    // and a "]". Then, returns that String
    return "[" + itemsAsText.joined(separator: ", ") + "]"
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your answer. I get it and really appreciate your time. I am learning swift and can have further questions to ask from you. Please be there to answer me :) Thank You so much.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take it piece by piece. This code:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: TextRepresentable {
    //...
}
```

defines an extension to types that conform to [`Collection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection), whose `Iterator.Element` is `TextRepresentable`. Looking at the documentation, we see that [`Array`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array) conforms to [`MutableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mutablecollection), which inherits from `Collection`. Thus, `Array` indirectly conforms to `Collection`. Your 
`hamsters` array is an `Array` (thus a `Collection`) whose elements are `Hamster`. Since `Hamster` is `TextRepresentable`, your `hamsters` array qualifies to receive this extension.

Now let's look at what this extension gives us:

```
var textualDescription: String {
    // ...
}
```

This is a computed property called `textualDescription`, which returns a `String`. This computed property becomes available on all types that are eligible for this extension. Delving deeper into how it works:

```
let itemsAsText = self.map { $0.textualDescription }
```

The items of this collection are transformed to an `Array` of their `textualDescription`s using [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641748-map). In your example, `[Hamster(name: "Murray"), Hamster(name: "Morgan"), Hamster(name: "Maurice")]` is mapped to `Array`: `["Murray", "Morgan", "Maurice"]`

```
return "[" + itemsAsText.joined(separator: ", ") + "]"
```

Then, all those textual descriptions are joined by `, "` to produce the string: `"Murray", "Morgan", "Maurice"`

Which are then wrapped with `[` and `]` to produce the final resulting String: `["Murray", "Morgan", "Maurice"]`

Let me know if you have any follow-up questions.